# Is there a way to shorten this YAML?

Tags: yaml

Is there a way to make the following YAML shorter so that the same resources aren't repeated?

```
---
  classes:
    - roles::storage::nfs
  samba::config::includeconf:
    - alpha
    - beta
    - charlie
    - delta
    - echo
    - foxtrot
  smb_shares:
    alpha:
      name: alpha
    beta:
      name: beta
    charlie:
      name: charlie
    delta:
      name: delta
    echo:
      name: echo
      path: /path/to/file
    foxtrot:
      name: foxtrot
```

If there's a way to reduce any of the repetition, that would be great.  Ideally, each resource name would only appear once.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can vastly reduce this with two optimisations, one of which nullifies most of the effect of the other. You will however have to change your program from reading in simple sequences and mappings to create smarter objects ( which I called `ShareInclude`, `Shares` and `Share`):

```
---
  classes:
    - roles::storage::nfs
  samba::config::includeconf: !ShareInclude
    - alpha
    - beta
    - charlie
    - delta
    - echo
    - foxtrot
  smb_shares: !Shares
    echo: !Share
      path: /path/to/file
```

When creating `ShareInclude`, you should create a `Share` for each sequence element with an initial name being the same as the scalar value and insert this in some global list.

The above takes care of most of the Share object, execept `info`. When

```
echo: !Share
  path: /path/to/file
```

is processed a temporary anonymous `Share` should be created with `path` set as an attribute or other retrievable value (if the name would be different that could be stored as well). Then once `Shares` is created it will know the name of the share to look up (`echo` from the key of the mapping) and take one of two actions:

1. If the name can be looked up, update the `Share` object with the information from the anonymous `Share`
2. If the name cannot be found, promote the anonymous share by providing the key value as its name, and store it.

This way you have to specify `echo` twice, otherwise there is no way to associate the explicit `path` with the specific `Share` object created when processing `ShareInclude`. If that is still too much you can approach it from the other way and leave `ShareInclude` empty and implicitly make those entries when dealing with `Shares`:

```
---
  classes:
    - roles::storage::nfs
  samba::config::includeconf: !ShareInclude
  smb_shares: !Shares
    alpha:
    beta:
    charlie:
    delta:
    echo:
      path: /path/to/file
    foxtrot:
```

Although this is somewhat shorter, depending on your YAML parser, you might no longer have a guaranteed ordering in the creation of the `Share` object. And if you have to make `Shares` into a sequence of key-value pairs the shortening advantage is gone.